# cout print string variable cannot pass the build

Tags: c++, string, cout

Could any one help me to figure out which the following code cannot build successfully:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void){

    std::string str1("sfsfasfdsdf");
    std::cout << str1 << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is error your compiler is giving you?

Answer (score 5):

You have to include `std::string` header:

```
#include <string>
```

**EDIT**: According to @ShafikYaghmour's comments, include `iostream` sometimes brings in `string`, but it may not be the case for you if you only have the posted code.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Would you please provide source of that? I never realized that this is the case, at least not on Windows.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: this is implementation-specific. Some do, others don't, the Standard doesn't mandate anything.

Comment: @syam I did not say the standard required it, I said depends, I am not sure we have enough information. Although it is a good guess. On ideone it build fine: http://ideone.com/xoChjb

Comment: I think is better and more clear if you specify the headers of the objects in the source file you are using them.

Comment: @user1655685 You are welcome. Glad it helped. You may accept my answer by clicking on the `\/` sign besides my answer.

Comment: On VS, bringing in some headers brings in enough of string's functionality to let you instantiate one, but not enough for all possible operations. I've seen many errors that goes along the 'huh, I can instantiate a string but not compare them?!' which is exactly this problem - always include the headers you need